# Spacing between TableView Section increases in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, ios4

I have an iPad app which is for both iOS 4 and iOS 5.

The problem is that the space between sections of grouped tableview is more in iOS 5 as compared to iOS 4.

The same table looks different because of more spaces between sections of tableView in iOS 5.

I tried setting Footer and Header height to 1.0 but still it looks quite different.

Has this changed in iOS 5?

What could be wrong?

**This is how it looks in iOS 5:**

[image]

I am doing nothing programmatically through code. Everything is set from IB.

Comment: Is that "Master Account Information" heading and its accompanying text in a custom view?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes. you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens because prior to iOS 5, table views would automatically re size the heights of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returned a nil view. 
In iOS5 and later we must return the actual height for each section headers.

I hope this will solev your issue :)